# Starting firefox with selenium ide enabled

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to launch Firefox with the Selenium IDE enabled so I can continue scripting where the test run ended. This is the code I am using at the moment:

```
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

    try {
        File seleniumide = new File("C:\\Downloads\\selenium-ide-2.8.0.xpi");
        profile.addExtension(seleniumide);
      } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

However when I run this Firefox opens but the button to launch the Selenium IDE is not displayed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found this solution on the web.

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7388

You have to unpack the xpi file by renaming to .zip and extracting the selenium-ide.xpi file only. Use the path to this file to set up your profile.